# Text Over Flow with ngx-ellipsis in Angular 8

Tags: css, angular, angular8

I have a name which is "**c0f6bd14-11ea-be017_001_lbl_017**" which is a combination of form name and some other attributes.
Now since it is very long, I want to shorten this name to show on the front-end. I am able to get in the form of "**c0f6bd14-11e...**", Now the thing is I want it in the form of first and last word i.e "**c0f6bd14-11e...017**"

What should I use?

Currently, I am using **ngx-ellipsis** and CSS are as follow:

```
.shortenText {
     width: 200px;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     overflow: hidden;
     white-space: nowrap;
     display:inline-block;
     right: -5px;
}
```

Comment: Hi! I'm the author of ngx-ellipsis and can confirm that it doesn't support this. The lib is only required for *multiline* ellipsis anyway - otherwise you may just use simple js as provided by Mileta Dulovic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function for it

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Helloworld!"; 
  var res = str.slice(0, 3) + '...';
  var res2 = str.slice(-3)
  var res3 = res + res2;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res3;
}
```

This will print `Hel...ld!`

I am sure it can be done better but you get the point

in `res` you store first `x` number of chars and append ... to it. in `res2` you get last 3 chars and append them to `res2`.

in `res3` you append those two results and show them..

Also. I am sorry for messy code. I am writing this from my phone :)

Hope this helped :)